# how do I make a SIP phone ring with sipsak?

Tags: networking, command-line, asterisk, voip, sip

How can I use sipsak to simulate a call so that there's an actual ring, or possibly even a sound is played?

```
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ sudo sipsak -v --usrloc-mode --from sip:demo_alice@localhost --password 123 --sip-uri sip:thufir@localhost
warning: ignoring -i option when in usrloc mode

All usrloc tests completed successful.
received last message 11.150 ms after first request (test duration).
thufir@mordor:~$
```